# Page Title Search SharePoint 2013

Tags: search, sharepoint-server, result-source

How can Page titles of the pages across the site collection become search key so that the result shows only matching pages and no other content? Can be done by merging two result sources, or how can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean? The title of pages are already searchable by default

Comment: searching for a particular page title yields to irrelevant results, it is working for some pages.Can i configure search for both title and name of all pages across the site collection

Comment: You can use the Title:"Name of a page" together with refiners for example

Comment: You should probably look if you can't configure your webpart (results webpart, content search, whichever you're using) to only show results of a given type (page content type maybe ?).

Comment: @RobertLindgren How can i do that ?? Cameron I've to show pages along with Everything P.S i am new to SharePoint

Comment: Robert means to put this as a filter in your search query box, I believe

Comment: Also, you know that the search crawler must first run before any results will show up in your search ?

Comment: Yeah I'been running full crawl on my content source

Comment: @RobertLindgren Are you asking me to create a managed Property that mapped to crawled Property 'ows_Title'??

Comment: Title should be available from the start, you can use (contentclass:"STS_ListItem_850" OR contentclass:"STS_Web) to only get publishing pages and webs

Comment: So to add something like this as a filter "(contentclass:"STS_ListItem_850" OR contentclass:"STS_Web") Title{SearchBoxQuery}"

Comment: @RobertLindgren Can you please elaborate a little bit what i supposed to do??

Comment: Sure can, if you stop adding double question marks after everything ;) Will add an answer below

Comment: @RobertLindgren May be those double question marks give you an idea how eagerly i need a solution.Waiting for your answer

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your situation correctly you can add a filter to the Search Results webpart on your search page.

1. Put the page in Edit mode, then Click the upper right corner of the Search Results Webpart and click "Edit WebPart"
2. Click "Change Query" in the properties section
3. In the "Query text" box, copy paste this: `(contentclass:"STS_ListItem_850" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem_WebPageLibrary" OR contentclass:"STS_Web") Title:{SearchBoxQuery}`
4. Click OK, Save, And Publish the page.

If you do a search now your webpart will show you publishing pages and webs that has a title matching the text put in the search box.

If you want to get hits on all properties, replace `Title:{SearchBoxQuery}` with `{SearchBoxQuery}`, it will still only show you pages and webs

Comment: I do believe you mean "Change Query", or were you trying to be subtle ;) ?

Comment: Are you certain about this syntax : Title{SearchBoxQuery} ? Does it not need an equals sign or a colon ?

Comment: Sorry, my dev environment has Swedish language ;) And surely I am missing a ":", will fix!

Comment: @RobertLindgren I've gone through all the steps "Title:{SearchBoxQuery}" failed to retrieve any results However "{SearchBoxQuery}" yeilds to pages but its matching keywords not the page title or name

Comment: Excuse me, but I do not really follow what you are trying to say

Comment: It works perfectly well in my site. What type of pages is it you are looking for?

Comment: Updated the query to include also webpages (wiki or webpart)

Comment: @RobertLindgren will this query will work for all pages  in the subsites within the site collection? i think thats the issue